# How to programmatically delete a display from a view

Tags: views

Is it possible to programmatically delete a display from a view?

The [view object](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/class/view/7) has numerous member functions related to displays (add_display, attach_displays, choose_display, set_display, new_display, etc.) and I can also disable a display like this:

```
<?php
  $view_name = "faq";
  $display_name = "page_1";
  $view = views_get_view($view_name);
  $view->display[$display_name]->display_options['enabled'] = FALSE;
  views_save_view($view);
?>
```

But I can't see how I can remove the display completely. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it. It is how it is done in [views_ui_edit_view_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!admin.inc/function/views_ui_edit_view_form_submit/7) when you delete a display via the admin UI:

```
unset($view->display[$display_name]);
```

Comment: I should have thought to look there. Thanks - that worked.